# Combine numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have three numpy arrays:

```
a1=np.array([5.048e-02, 2.306e+00, 0.000e+00])

a2=np.array([1.018e-01, 4.077e+00, 0.100e+00])

a3=np.array([1.02e-01, 5.077e+00, 0.200e+00])
```

As a combined result I would like to have:

```
array(
 [5.048e-02, 1.018e-01, 1.02e-01],
 [2.306e+00, 4.077e+00, 5.077e+00],
 [0.000e+00, 0.100e+00, 0.200e+00]
)
```

How can I do this with numpy?
(Please excuse me for the error.)

Comment: `np.vstack([a1, a2, a3])`

Comment: what have you tried?  There are several waya, but you may need a `transpose`

Comment: @hpaulj: how is the solution with transpose?

Answer (score 1):

```
np.array([a1,a2,a3])
```

Just create a new numpy array from those three individual array.

Comment: he may want its transpose